# Elements in the react-virtualized-select dropdown not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to use React Virtualized Select https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized-select for drop down but getting an issue with displaying elements not sure which particular css is causing this issue

[image]

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: i beleive this issue is related to css and the css is available at https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized-select within not js code

Comment: This component is used inside in your code . Again, where is your code ?